# How to get json array from file, format with jq and curl a post request with ddata from json

Tags: json, curl, jq, git-bash, xargs

I'm trying to get an array from a json file.

```
{
    "Requests": [
        {
            "Item1": "2020-01-27 16:24:49",
            "Item2": "203i1Kj2gTEQgfdsfds23",
            "Item3": 1603,
            "Item4": "generic"
        },
        {
            "Item1": "2020-01-27 16:24:49",
            "Item2": "203i1Kj2gTEQgfdsfds23",
            "Item3": 1603,
            "Item4": "generic"
        },
        {
            "Item1": "2020-01-27 16:24:49",
            "Item2": "203i1Kj2gTEQgfdsfds23",
            "Item3": 1603,
            "Item4": "generic"
        },
        {
            "Item1": "2020-01-27 16:24:49",
            "Item2": "203i1Kj2gTEQgfdsfds23",
            "Item3": 1603,
            "Item4": "generic"
        }
    ]
}
```

Then I want to pass each of these items to a curl request and possibly handle that in parralel with xargs

I'm still stumbling on getting one item to the curl endpoint.

```
cat CurlArgsFile.json | jq -c '.[][0]' | xargs -I % curl -d % -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST http://localhost:53391/mySVCS/writeData
```

I'm running this on Git Bash on Windows 10. When I try to echo the json output into a file I get the below without the quotes and now I'm not sure if that's the correct json I'm sending at all.

```
{Item1:2020-01-27 16:24:49,Item2:203i1Kj2gTEQgfdsfds23,Item3:1603,Item4:generic}
```

How do I send the first item from the json to the endpoint and the enpoint recognizes it?

Comment: to what exactly do you refer with "first item"? The first element in the array? BTW why does your array have 4 identical elements?

Comment: `.Requests[0]`?

Comment: @derpirscher First item in the array, yes. [0]. It's just an example. I forgot to mention and will edit the post in a bit. I'm running this on git bash in windows and for some reason I cannot reach the endpoint.

Comment: @AndreasLouv I'm getting a request error. If I just put raw json in my curl command I can reach the endpoint fine.

curl -d '{
 "Item1": "2020-01-27 16:24:49",
 "Item2": "203i1Kj2gTEQgfdsfds23",
 "Item3": 1,
 "Item4": "generic"
}' -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST http://localhost:53391/mySVCS/writeData

Comment: No, if you don't have quotes in your JSON it's not valid. Not sure though, why git bash swallows them

Comment: @derpirscher I'm thinking the same, must be a windows thing. I did not stumble on anyone having a similar issue so decided I would post here for my sanity sake. Will update the post later on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the end result. The issue was I was not familiar with the jq utility and my json kept coming in wrong.

```
cat CurlArgsFile.json | jq -r '.Requests[]|tojson' | xargs -0 -I % curl -d % -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST http://localhost:53391/mySVC/writeData
```

Comment: You can simplify to `jq -c '.Requests[]' CurlArgsFile.json | xargs ...`

Comment: @Philippe If I don't use the |tojson after the Requests[] it will not be properly formatted with double-quotes

Comment: The code I suggested should output exactly the same result as you version.

Comment: @Artexias You're using `tojson` to generate a JSON string containing a compact JSON-encoded object. Using the `-r` flag then converts that JSON string into raw text, leaving you with just that string's content, ie. the compact JSON-encoded object. Without using `tojson`, the jq filter result would remain to be a JSON object which is output directly as is, regardless of any `-r` flag which would only affect string results. However, jq will attempt to pretty-print the result, unless the `-c` flag is given which would skip the pretty-printing and output just the same compact JSON-encoded object.

Answer (score 0):

If you use GNU `xargs`, the `-d` flag is usefule:

```sh
jq '.Requests[]' -rc file.json |
  xargs -d '\n' -0 -P0 -I@ curl -X POST -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d @ http://localhost:53391/mySVC/writeData
```

Otherwise, use `tr` to make it compatible with other `xargs` such as BSD or BusyBox.

```sh
jq '.Requests[]' -rc file.json |
  tr '\n' '\0' |
  xargs -0 -P0 -I@ curl -X POST -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d @ http://localhost:53391/mySVC/writeData
```